# WSO2ESB Synapse Handler

Tags: java, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2.
I am trying to get a SynapseHandler working on WSO2ESB v5.0.0.

```
public class TestHandler implements SynapseHandler...
```

I build it into a jar. I then deploy it into ESB Artifacts.
Stop the server.
Add the entry into synapse-handlers.xml.

```
<handler name="TestHandler" class="x.y.z.TestHandler"/>
```

I start the server and get the following error:

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.y.z.TestHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v7**

Even though the jar is found:

**INFO - ExtensionDeployer Loading extensions from: C:....\wso2esb-5.0.0\repository\deployment\server\extensions\TestHandler-0.0.1.jar**

I have nothing in the methods except system outs.
Example followed [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Writing+a+Synapse+Handler#WritingaSynapseHandler-EngagingtheSynapsehandler)

Using wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole, followed by ss in osgi console, shows no jar loaded, because of error.

Any idea as to what I missed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your JAR to repository/components/lib directory. Can you try adding it there?

Comment: The first time I tried, got a ClassNotFoundException for org/apache/synapse/SynapseHandler, which was weird. I reinstalled a clean server deployed it to repository/components/lib and it worked. So using the ESB Artifacts uploading, is wrong, or is it a ClassLoader issue? I'm guessing ClassLoader.

Comment: Seems a class loading issue, Glad you could get it solved.